# How the save autoincrement values using laravel eloquent

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

I am trying to save data into a database using Laravel eloquent models. However, the primary key is an auto-increment integer and it's throwing an error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'property_valuation_id' doesn't have a default value.

Any help on how this can be solved.

Here is the controller:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $property_valuation = new PropertValuation();
    $property_valuation->property_valuation_id="";
    $property_valuation->integer('property_valuation_id')->default(1);
    $property_valuation->district_id = $request->input('district');
    $property_valuation->propertyneighbourhood = $request->input('neighborhood');
    $property_valuation->propertystreet = $request->input('street');
    $property_valuation->numberofbedrooms =$request->input('bedrooms');
    $property_valuation->currency=$request->input('currency');
    $property_valuation->monthlyrent=$request->input('rent');

    $property_valuation->save();
}
```

And here the model:

```
class PropertValuation extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'property_valuation';
    public $primaryKey = 'property_valuation_id';
    public $timestamps = false;
}
```

Comment: Could you show us the model and the controller method in which the error is occurring?

Comment: check the question again for the code

Comment: Removing the lines complains with SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'property_valuation_id' doesn't have a default value

Comment: Are you sure that the sql table actually has a primary key with auto increment?

Answer (score 0):

You're overwriting Laravels default behaviour with this lines

```
$property_valuation->property_valuation_id="";
$property_valuation->integer('property_valuation_id')->default(1);
```

Remove it and it should be ignored within the SQL query and the auto-increment value should be set.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should use

```
$table->bigIncrements('property_valuation_id');
or
$table->increments('property_valuation_id');
```

in your migration file and then run in console **php artisan migration:fresh** to update your db structure. Aslo your why you are using custom field increment name instead of default 'id' ?

Second you must do is to set value for fillable variable in your Model. No need to include autoincrement field in this array.

```
protected $fillable = ['neighborhood', 'district',.....];
```

And the last thing. It is unnessessary to set all values for model from request, laravel do it itself. So your controller store method  might be

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
   PropertValuation::create($request->all());

   return redirect()->back();
}
```

Much cleaner, yeah? :)